How do I play audio through ssh without using the sound card through physical login first?
I have a Raspberry Pi with Gentoo on it that I use to play audio through. The idea is that I log in through ssh, then play the audio from the command line. But when I ssh into it without having physically logged in first and use the sound card through alsamixer I get:
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: File or directory not found
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: File or directory not found
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/confmisc.c:1342:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: File or directory not found
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/conf.c:5727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: File or directory not foundccc
ALSA lib /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/alsa-lib-1.2.11/work/alsa-lib-1.2.11/src/control/control.c:1570:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
Error when opening mixer: File or directory not found

More generally, I can't play audio at this point. If I first log in physically and call alsamixer, then use alsamixer through ssh, then it works and I can play audio as well. So I guess somehow I can activate the sound card through my physical login in a way that I can't just by using it through ssh, and once it is activated I can use it through ssh as well. How can I activate my sound card without having to physically log in?
Edit: it seems ssh does not assign a seat to my sessions.

when you run loginctl when logged in (only) via ssh, does it show that the SSH session is assigned a seat?

(and you don't "call" soundcards; you can basically only "call" software functions in a computer context; I think what you mean is "use", but I'm not sure)

@MarcusMüller apparently not.

You'll need to assign a seat to your SSH session. The idea behind "seats" is that only one user session at a time uses a screen and a soundcard (the security motivation here is straightforward: Don't allow other people logged in via SSH to listen to your session's audio output, or modify it). So, your SSH session needs to be "the owner" of the audio output of your RPi.

To be frank, I doubt that there is a better way for this than just granting the permission to the user by some (other) means. Usually it would be adding your user to the audio group. Certainly that could get you into problems if you would e.g. start two local session logged in as different users, but at the same time, obviously you may not even do that at all. assign a seat to your SSH session I'm not quite sure if that could make sense, even if it's possible in a certain way.

Thanks to Markus Müller and Tom Yan, I now know much better what the problem seems to be. I'm using Pipewire, and as part of making it work I took my user out of the audio group. Moreover, the Pi also doesn't assign a seat to me if I log in through ssh. What I ended up doing to solve the problem were neither of the two suggestions though. Rather, I configured my default user, which is logged in automatically and so gets assigned a seat, to automatically start a detached tmux-session. When I want to play audio, I just attach that tmux-session in my terminal, and I'm set!

If having your user in the audio group didn't get it to work, then what was missing was just that the audio devices are not owned by the the group or the owner group doesn't have permission to access it, probably because you distro overidden / excluded some udev rules shipped upstream. All the seat / session stuff do is getting an ACL set on the audio device, which means you do not need to attach to a "seatful" session whatsoever. All you need (if you insist on this approach) is the session to be "active" (i.e. its tty is the one on screen).
